# How to use AWSCLI to get a formatted list of a security group's ingress rules?

Tags: aws-cli, aws-security-group

How do you do, fellow kids?  I am trying to use the AWSCLI to query for a security groups list of ingress rules.  I am pretty close, but not quite there yet.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id $sgid --region $reg --profile $acct --query "SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[][].{P:IpProtocol,R:IpRanges}" --output text
tcp
R   10.0.0.0/8  allow for homerun
-1
R   10.12.1.229/32
R   10.227.84.26/32
R   10.26.230.100/32
R   10.26.230.106/32
R   10.230.84.39/32
R   10.28.164.101/32
R   10.28.164.100/32 
R   10.227.84.27/32
R   10.14.240.7/32
R   10.26.230.101/32
R   10.14.240.8/32
R   10.230.84.40/32
R   10.26.230.104/32
udp
R   10.0.0.0/8  allow for homerun
```

What I would like is something more like this:

```
tcp 10.0.0.0/8      allow for homerun
-1  10.12.1.229/32
-1  10.227.84.26/32
...
udp 10.0.0.0/8      allow for homerun
```

with the details of each rule displayed on the same line, so it can be more easily read by another script.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: You will need to write your own program to do this, using a language such as Python or bash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, all in bash, in case you, as I did, want to keep it simple:

```
case "$dir" in
    ingress)
        query="SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[][].{P:IpProtocol,R:IpRanges,F:FromPort,T:ToPort}" 
        ;;
    egress)
        query="SecurityGroups[].IpPermissionsEgress[][].{P:IpProtocol,R:IpRanges,F:FromPort,T:ToPort}"
        ;; 
esac

aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id $sgid --region $reg --profile $acct \
--query $query --output text|while read line; 
do 
    cnt=$(echo $line|wc -w)
    if [ $cnt -eq 3 ]; then
        from=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f1)
        proto=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f2)
        to=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f3)
    # this assumes the comment is not gonna be 1 word.  Lets hope :)
    else
        trash=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f1)
        cidr=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f2)
        remain=$(echo ${line//$trash/}) 
        remain2=$(echo ${remain//$cidr/})       
        comment="$remain2"
        out+=";"
        out+="$proto:$cidr:$from:$to:$comment"
    fi 
    echo $out>$TMPFILE
done
```